# UIImageView view Image from Left to Right

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview

So I have a big image in an UIImageView (Swift) with "Aspect Fill"

But What I want is to have like an Animation or Ken Burn Effect on the Image.

In the Image Below... What I want is to go from Red to Yellow seen the image.

[image]

[image: Original Image]

[image: UIImageView]

Comment: I would suggest you add the imageview to a scroll view and then you can simply move the scrollview

Comment: I want to make it automatically, like an animation... If I put a Scroll the user will need to interact with the image.

Comment: No, you can scroll the scrollview using an animation block

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a normal uiview give it proper height width as per ur wish... Take an imageview inside of it and give the height, x coordinate and y coordinate same as uiview and keep the width as much wide you want to keep the image....

Use UIView.animateWithDuration method and in its animation block set the final desired frame such that the end of image view comes equal to the end of uiview... The image view will slide outside of vision of the uiview as you desire...

You can even repeatedly animate from left to right calling animation into each others completion block

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: I hope you have played with frames which are CGRect and CGRectMake classes.... Use a views restriction of view that doesnt let you see anything out of it bounds cause of its property clipToBounds.... And refer to this documentation to let about animation https://www.raywenderlich.com/113674/ios-animation-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

I found an extension for UIImageView called [UIImageViewAligned](https://github.com/sochalewski/UIImageViewAlignedSwift). You can use the alignment properties provided by the extension and animate the changes.

```
import UIKit
import UIImageViewAligned

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageViewAligned!

    // MARK: Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView?.alignLeft = true
        imageView?.alignRight = false
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {
            self.imageView?.alignLeft = false
            self.imageView?.alignRight = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I have a PageViewController and is giving me like a nil image and error